# Add a click handler to a HorizontalPanel in GWT

Tags: java, events, gwt, onclick

How do i add click handlers to `HorizontalPanel`?

It worked with the use of `addDomHandler()` in newer GWT versions, but i had to downgrade to GWT 2.0.4 where this isn't supported. I used to do it like this:

```
horizontalPanel.getWidget(1).addDomHandler(someClickHandler,ClickEvent.getType());
//or
horizontalPanel.addDomHandler(someClickHandler, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use FocusPanels instead of hooking native events. To catch clicks for the whole panel:

```
FocusPanel wrapper = new FocusPanel();
HorizontalPanel panel = new HorizontalPanel();
wrapper.add(panel);
wrapper.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // Handle the click
  }
});

// Add wrapper to the parent widget that previously held panel.
```

Or to catch clicks inside a cell in the HorizontalPanel:

```
IsWidget child; // Any widget
HorizontalPanel panel = new HorizontalPanel();
FocusPanel clickBox = new FocusPanel();

clickBox.add(child);
panel.add(clickBox);

clickBox.addClickHandler(...);
```