# How to remove GWT menubar on Screen click?

Tags: java, events, gwt, menubar

I am a beginner using GWT. I have a `menubar` which pops-up on a `Label click`. I need to remove it when the user clicks anywhere on screen except the Label which caused it to display (Legal) I tried various methods like hooking up this event on

`RootPanel.get().addDomHandler(clickDetectHandler, ClickEvent.getType());`

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (!(source instanceof MenuBar))
                  panel.remove(menu);
```

[image]

I even tried using the `MouseOutEvent` but it doesn't detect click. I am able to remove it on a click back to the `legal label`. But I need it to be removed on detecting a click on the screen. Please advise.

Comment: the if condition suggests that it should be removed if click is on the MenuBar.

Comment: Do you mean, when you click on Legal, the vertical panel including Toronto, Chicago becomes visible, and when you click somewhere else, you want that to go away?

Comment: @Swapnil exactly. Its a GWT menubar. On the legal click handler, I am adding the menubar in the flowpanel. Legal is a label also part of the same flowpanel

Comment: @Sednus: I tried hooking the onclick event both on RootPanel.get() and MenuBar.

Comment: As @Sednus suggested, code seems to remove it when the click event source is an instance of MenuBar. Shouldn't it be the other way?

Comment: @Swapnil it was a typo. I tried to see what the name of the instance class was. It is always Rootpanel...something, no matter where u click

Comment: Instead of the `addDomHandler`, can you try using a `FocusPanel`? Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942140/add-a-click-handler-to-a-horizontalpanel-in-gwt

Comment: @Swapnil the instance is always a focus panel.

Answer (score 1):

GWT has a panel called PopupPanel which automatically handles exactly the behaviour that you want.
Quoting from the javadoc:

*"PopupPanel's constructor takes 'auto-hide' as its boolean parameter.
 If this is set, the panel closes itself automatically when the user clicks outside of it."*

Is it possible to have the pop-up menu display inside of a PopupPanel?

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwMenuBar) GWT sample. This seems to have the behaviour you describe. It comes with source code.

Alternatively you can try handling the [blur event](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/BlurEvent.html) on the menu widget.